# Texture rendering looks different from preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, export, transparency

I created a 3d duck with png alpha feathers.
I merged feathers to the body of the duck.
Cycles rendered preview is cool but when I export the feathers take the unalpha texture of the body (not of the feathers)
[image: bird]
[image: wrong bird]

[image]

Comment: Could You provide the scene file? I have to see the setup buddy...

Comment: Also, where are you exporting it to?

Comment: Welcome, Paolo Bertolotto.Could you upload the file for analysis?  Use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the blend file, I'm a beginner, there should be some errors. I export the png file onto my hdd via cycles render

Answer (score 2):

*I almost give it up :)*

---

You have set body material in *View Layer Properties* > **Override** - you have to disable it.

[image]

Second thing is your **UVMap - rotated 90 deg.** = squized image.
If you would like to fix it, it would be such painful unwrap each feather so I would suggest just to rotate original images to landscape orintation.

[image]

Third thing is - "someone" wanted paint feather to brown and **destroyed alpha** channels. I saw some separated alphas (masks) packed in your file, so you would probably use them instead original ones.

Funny, with all these errors, it is looking cool in Worbench engine :)

[image]

Note to Normals direction - if you will have some shading issue in render,
select all faces and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

---

*Nice flight, your forensic team from future, in hope message will be delivered on time :)*

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you mean with the last 11 words...

Next time you upload a scene, especially if the topic is the textures, please import the textures into the file with "File -> External Data -> Pack all into .blend".
I looked at the unwrap of a single feather and depending on your texture, this could be broken (besides from the triangulation, which is weird but not causing the problem, you are unwrapping a rectangular shape to a square):[image]

Also please state to which format you are exporting. Could be that, as you got 25 different materials on that duck, the file format does not support that? (Which doesnt seem to be the case here, just a thing to think about)

And last but not least, you have serious troubles with your normals, as you can see on the right wing: [image]

(PLEASE DONT DOWNVOTE ME, THIS MESSAGE IS TOO LONG FOR A COMMENT, I KNOW ITS NOT AN ANSWER AS IS, BUT I WANTED TO POINT ALL THAT STUFF OUT)

Comment: Ok great, about normals, I have feathers on both parts of both wings, do they have to face the extern? I reuploaded the .blend file!

Comment: Tringulation is common for imported models. Square UVMap means nothing it always stretches to image proportions, since you assign some rectangle image UVMap become rectangled. Normal orientation - ussually affects shading issue, but Im not sure if it has influence here in this case.